# Manipulating SQLite Data in C# or String Manipulation for Image Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, sqlite

I'm working on a project that involves a SQLite database and a bunch of images. Everything will be put into an external hard drive, and everything is read-only (no CRUD stuff).

The database contains a table for Photos, with one of the columns (named Path) being paths (strings) to the photos. I want to use a Telerik Rotator to show these photos (which is inside a RadWindow which opens after choosing a row in a RadGrid if that helps you any.)

My problem is: the paths need to be changed. Each one starts with H:\, which I need removed, and replaced with ~/ThisFolder/ (which just points to ../ThisFolder). For every other part of the project, using `ResolveUrl("~/ThisFolder/" + path.Remove(0, 3))` has worked, but I can't figure out how to do it here.

**I either need to manipulate the data in the Path column after putting the SQLite data into a DataTable or manipulate the Path strings later on before it goes into the asp:Image tag.**

Here's how I'm grabbing the data from the SQLite database and putting it into a DataTable:

```
    public static DataTable dtTable;
    public static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entity"].ConnectionString;
    public SQLiteConnection SQLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
    public SQLiteDataAdapter SQLiteDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
    public SQLiteCommand SQLiteCommand = new SQLiteCommand();    

private void GetDataSource() //called in Page_Load
    {
        dtTable = new DataTable();
        SQLiteConnection.Open();
        try
        {
            string selectQuery = "SELECT ParentTableID, PhotoID, Path FROM tblPhoto";
            SQLiteCommand myCommand = new SQLiteCommand(selectQuery, SQLiteConnection);
            using (SQLiteDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dtTable.Load(myReader);
            }
            RadRotator1.DataSource = dtTable;
        }
        finally
        {
            SQLiteConnection.Close();
        }
        RadRotator1.DataBind();
    }
```

And here's my asp tag, so far:

```
<asp:Image ID="Images" runat="server" AlternateText="Images" ImageUrl='<%#Bind("~/ThisFolder/{0}", "Path")%>' />
```

Though the ImageURL would be ../ThisFolder/H:/yadayada here....

Any help would be much appreciated! Feel free to ask questions if I'm not being clear somewhere.

Comment: I meant 3.5 or 4.0, etc. as there was discussion about adding some string handling attributes directly to binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try SQLLite's [replace](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace).

`SELECT ParentTableID, PhotoID, replace(Path,'H:\','') as Path FROM tblPhoto`

Comment: replace did change the data, but it also changed the column name from Path to replace(Path,'H:\',''). This lead to the asp:Image tag not finding the Path column.

Comment: I've updated the statement.  It should keep the column name now.

Comment: Got it! `SELECT ParentTableID, PhotoID, replace(Path,'H:\','..\\ThisFolder') as Path FROM tblPhoto` in the C#, and `<asp:Image ID="Images" runat="server" AlternateText="Images" Width="100%" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Path")%>' />` in the C#. Thanks for all your help!